# SwiftUI Delay on view variable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I got a class with a function that gets the username for printing it on the view.
It works, but I got a delay of nearly a second where the username is not seen.

here the class :

```
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {


@Published var username: String = ""





func benutzerdaten_accountview (email: String) -> String {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("Nutzer").document(email)
    docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
        
        if let document = document, document.exists{
            self.username = (document.data()!["username"] as? String)!
    }
   }
    return username
  }

}
```

This is how I print it on the view :

```
struct AccountView: View{

@ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
@Binding var tabSelection: Int
var email: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!

var body: some View {
    
        VStack{
            
            Text("Hallo, \(model.benutzerdaten_accountview(email: email).description)")
         ...
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if the correct `username` is actually returned. By the looks of it, I don't think it would change from the original empty string, until after. So the return is pointless for a value set in an asynchronous closure.

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: We don’t use view models in SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `benutzerdaten_accountview()`, you can't return `username` because it isn't already set yet. The username is set in an asynchronous closure.

You *are* already setting `username` in the callback closures already, so that's good. What you need to do now is just call the method in `onAppear(perform:)` so it shows as soon as `AccountView` loads.

The changing of `username` will publish an update to update the view again, **when** it is ready. Fetching data from an API can take time, especially when you have [cold-starts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_start_(computing)).

Firstly, remove the `return` and the return type in that `benutzerdaten_accountview()` method. This is no longer needed. Rest of code:

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
    @Binding var tabSelection: Int
    var email: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hallo, \(model.username)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.benutzerdaten_accountview(email: email)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you, but I still got this delay. On the first start of the app the username is blank for a whole second

Comment: @kaan5353 That the nature of calling an API on the internet, and also cold-starts as I mentioned. To solve this on the client side, you can save that value locally if you want.